# AngularJS function call causes application stop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Look at this piece of code:

```
// Start AngularJS Application
var application = angular.module('engineers', []);
// Set controller
application.controller('engineers_controller', function($scope) {
    // Seting page meta information
    $scope.description = 'Some Description', $scope.keywords = 'key1,key2,key3', $scope.application_name = 'Sarabon', $scope.googleplus_url = '#', $scope.page_title = 'مهندسین مشاور سرابن',
    $scope.txt1="Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows. Some pilots get picked and become television programs. Some don't, become nothing. She starred in one of the ones that became nothing.",
    $scope.txt2="You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man.",
    $scope.switch1=function(){
        $scope.activetext=$scope.txt1,
        $scope.firstswitcher='fa fa-square';
        $scope.secondswitcher='fa fa-square-o';
    },
    $scope.switch2=function(){
        $scope.activetext=$scope.txt2,
        $scope.secondswitcher='fa fa-square';
        $scope.firstswitcher='fa fa-square-o';
    };
    switch1();
});
```

I tried to call `switch1()` function `onpageloads`. but when I run my page, almost all of page is ruined and doesn't work properly. when I delete `switch1();` from code, It works properly again. What's wrong with the code? and how can I do that properly?

Comment: Please update your question with function and also mention where it intilized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `switch1` doesn't exist. You probably meant to write `$scope.switch1();` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the problem solved, I've to wait 11 minutes to select as solved :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

When you call `switch1()` on your controller what will actually get executed is `$scope.switch1()`, which is the correct way to do it and this is what you should be calling. As you say deleting `switch1()` makes your code work again, so you've already answered this for yourself.